# How to fix these two angled boundaries in Maple

Tags: python, matlab, maple, wave

I have this animation done on Maple. I want the two sides which meet at a point to be fixed. The same way the other two straight sides are. Is it possible in Maple, and if not, is it possible to do it in MatLab and how?

```
with(plots):
animate(plot3d,[sin(Pi*(t-x))*sin(Pi*y)*Heaviside(t-x)-sin(Pi*(t+x))*sin(Pi*y)*Heaviside(t+x),x=0..4,y=piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2-x/4,0)..piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2+x/4,1)],t=-2*Pi..2*Pi, frames=90);
```

Thanks a lot.

[image: Image on what it look like at t=0 in Maple]

Comment: Why is the question tagged `python`?

Comment: It was recommended. To be fair if python gives the answer, I don't mind writing it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original,

```
with(plots):

animate(plot3d,
    [sin(Pi*(t-x))*sin(Pi*y)*Heaviside(t-x)
     -sin(Pi*(t+x))*sin(Pi*y)*Heaviside(t+x),
     x=0..4,
     y=piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2-x/4,0)
       ..piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2+x/4,1)],
    t=-2*Pi..2*Pi, frames=90);
```

[image]

Is this what you're after?

```
with(plots):

adjustor:=sin(Pi*piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,(y-1/2)/(x/2)+1/2,y)):

animate(plot3d,
        [sin(Pi*(t-x))*adjustor*Heaviside(t-x)
         -sin(Pi*(t+x))*adjustor*Heaviside(t+x),
         x=0..4,
         y=piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2-x/4,0)
           ..piecewise(x>=0 and x<2,1/2+x/4,1)],
         t=-2*Pi..2*Pi, frames=45);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I have been working on this for ages now. Can I also ask would it be possible to have an equation in Maple such that a wave moves towards these two sides which are slopped inwards and then bounce off at the correct angle. As if I was using this wave to represent a light wave and the two slopped lines are mirror. At the moment the wave is just being reflected straight back out. Someone told me that it wasn't possible in Maple, but he also told me that fixing these two lines wasn't possible either, which it is as you have shown. Thanks again for this.

Comment: Why do you want it fixed at height 0 along the two sloped line segments? How does that allow for reflection?

Comment: I can think of two ways that should be workable. 1) plottools:-reflect the plots of the strip (as if continued past x=0), then add the z-heights of coincident plots. 2) plot larger region with piecewise translations of domains of the reflected strips. But this should be a wholly separate Question. And the surface should not be fixed along the triangular edges.

Comment: As I wrote, it should be a wholly separate Question.